# How to resize a Flutter Table Calendar

Tags: flutter, dart

New to Flutter. I need to show a Calendar and some content below, so I need to make the Calendar smaller. I've tried using a SizedBox like this:

```
Column(
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      height: 500,
      child: TableCalendar(
        firstDay: firstDay,
        lastDay: lastDay,
        focusedDay: focusedDay)),
    Text("Content goes \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhere")
  ],
),
```

But this just clips it. How do I resize the Calendar properly?

Update: a FittedBox doesn't work, if you put in width it resizes correctly, but the height still just clips

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went through their source code and I found `shouldFillViewport` which solves your use case.

You also need to wrap your `TableCalendar` inside an `Expanded` widget.

```
 Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 500,
          width: 300,
          child: TableCalendar(
              shouldFillViewport: true,
              firstDay: DateTime(2020),
              lastDay: DateTime(2021),
              focusedDay: DateTime(2020),
        ),
      ),
      Text("Content goes \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhere")
    ],
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: That gives an error

`RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded`
, which seems to originate in the table_calendar API

Comment: Can you give your `SizedBox` a width as well ?

Comment: which package are you using?

Comment: table_calendar, which is supposed to be autosizing

Comment: Added a picture as well. Is that what you intended ?

Comment: Im using `table_calendar` and this avoided the overflows but I couldnt control the height. Everything is all over the whole screen and looks really bad. The month seems not to fit the width and is aligned vertically

Comment: Place your TableCalendar inside a Container with constraints of height = your intended height. This might solve your issue.

Comment: Expanded and sizedbox do not change the size, unfortunately. Even if I force hard, overflow happens this way.

Screenshot : https://imgur.com/a/5sfxdyB

Answer (score 0):

have to specify width also.

code would be

```
  Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: 500,
        width: 300,
        child: TableCalendar(
          firstDay: DateTime(2021, 1, 1),
          lastDay: DateTime(2021, 9, 1),
          focusedDay: DateTime.now()
        )
      ),
      Text("Content goes here")
    ],
  ),
```

modify the height, width as per your need.

Update:

for fix bottom overflow wrap Sizedbox with Expanded

Like:

```
  Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 500,
          width: 300,
          child: TableCalendar(
            firstDay: DateTime(2021, 1, 1),
            lastDay: DateTime(2021, 9, 1),
            focusedDay: DateTime.now()
          )
        ),
      ),
      Text("Content goes here")
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: This correctly sizes the width, but the height still just clips and throws
`A RenderFlex overflowed by x pixels on the bottom`

Comment: wrap SizedBox with Expanded widget, see the update